# Python version compatibility with Windows Server 2003

Tags: python, version, windows-server-2003

Which versions of python are compatible with Windows Server 2003? I'm using 32-bit (x86)

Can versions 3.x be installed?

Why I'm asking is because I've installed Python 3.5.2 on Windows Server 2003 and when I try to run it, it gives me an error "python.exe is not a valid Win32 application"

Comment: `python.exe is not a valid Win32 application` means that windows does not recognize the exe as an (Win32) application by looking at the first bytes (header) of it - so windows will not even try to run it.

Comment: But i used the 32-bit installer

Comment: Windows not recognizing it does not necessaryly mean thet the app is broken but just that this application format is not supported in this version of windows (but possibly different/later/earlier versions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [official Site](https://www.python.org/) (when pointing the mouse on Downloads) states that you cannot use Python 3.5+ on Windows XP and earlier (implying that earlier versions are usable) - Windows Server 2003 has many parts in common with XP so *propably* 3.5+ will not work there, too.

Note that 64-bit versions do not work on 32-bit operationg systems - regardless wether the hardware supports 64-bit-programs.

To be on the safe side just install [3.4](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-344/) for Windows x86 or [2.7](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-2712/) for Windows x86.

Comment: install 3.4 for Windows x86 or 2.7 for Windows x86 - this a typo?